# Почему в перле слабая типизация?

Tags: perl

Где в перле слабая типизация? Для строк и чисел существуют разные операторы, таким образом, конвертация между ними не является *неявной*.

Answer (score 5):

Для начала вспомним, какие встроенные типы данных имеются в Perl:

> Perl has **three** built-in **data types**: scalars, arrays of scalars, and
>   associative arrays of scalars, known as "hashes".

а также определимся с терминологией:

> All data in Perl is a scalar, an array of scalars, or a hash of
>   scalars.  A scalar may contain one single value in any of three
>   different **flavors**: a number, a string, or a reference.

И обратим внимание на причины подобного автоматического преобразования.

> Scalars aren't necessarily one thing or another.  **There's no place to
>   declare a scalar variable to be of type "string", type "number", type
>   "reference", or anything else**.  Because of the **automatic conversion of
>   scalars, operations that return scalars don't need to care (and in
>   fact, cannot care) whether their caller is looking for a string, a
>   number, or a reference**.  Perl is a contextually polymorphic language
>   whose scalars can be strings, numbers, or references (which includes
>   objects).

http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Ещё раз удостоверимся что всевозможные преобразования происходят лишь с форматом, а не с типом:

> Perl operations which take a numeric argument treat that argument in
>   one of four different ways: they may force it to one of the
>   integer/floating/ string formats, or they may behave differently
>   depending on the format of the operand.  Forcing a numeric value to a
>   particular format does not change the number stored in the value.
>
> ...
>
> **Though forcing an argument into a particular form does not change the
>   stored number**, Perl remembers the result of such conversions. In
>   particular, though the first such conversion may be time-consuming,
>   repeated operations will not need to redo the conversion.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html

#### Сводка

1. У Perl есть лишь три типа данных: скаляры, массивы скаляров и хэши скаляров.
2. Скаляр может содержать значение в трёх различных **формах**: число, строка и ссылка.
3. Так как в Perl, нет места для предварительного объявления скаляра в виде конкретного типа "строка", "число" и "ссылка", как это сделано например в C, то компилятор не может знать, наверняка, какую именно **форму** скаляра от него требует конкретное преобразование или вызывающая функция, возвращающая скаляр:

   ```
   $result = get_foobar(); # $result может быть числом, строкой или ссылкой
   ```
4. В случае надобности Perl производит преобразование форм, но не самих типов.

Таким образом типизация в Perl весьма конкретная, состоящая из трёх типов, а уж сама конвертация между их формами, а если точнее между формами скаляра, может быть как явной так и неявной, в зависимости от применённой операции к ним.

Comment: Отлично, а можно теперь пример неявной конвертации?

Comment: @SmitJohnth `perl -E '$a = 3; say "YES" if $a eq "3";`

Comment: `eq` конвертирует операнды в строки.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, да, конвертирует формы скаляров, о чём и написано в ответе. P.S. Хамить вот только не советую.

Comment: edem вы здесь модератор? :) В таком случае, хотя бы читайте вопрос до конца. Там ровно 2 предложения. Где в вашем примере *неявная* конвертация, если программист используя строковой оператор сравнения явно требует конвертации в строки?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Дайте своё определение неявного преобразования, а также примеры его.

Comment: @dionys Пример из javascript: `'3'+5 == 35`. Оператор `+` есть у строк и чисел. Если один из операндов - число, а другой - строка, то число приводится к строке. Т.е. тип, в который конвертируется операнд, определяется вторым операндом, а не задается явно программистом, как в перле.

Comment: @SmitJohnth Это пример перегрузки оператора, а не неявного преобразования, хотя оно там тоже происходит. Неявное приведение типов же подразумевает преобразование всех операндов к одному типу перед выполнением операции. В Perl это и происходит и с форматами (потому что представления в нужном формате создаются налету) и с настоящими типами, например, при сложении скаляра с массивом.

Comment: @dionys К какому типу? Чем/кем определяется этот тип?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Тип определяется правилами приведения типов. Например, складывая целое и с плавающей запятой, мы приводим операнды к типу с плавающей запятой, потому что таково правило.

Comment: @dionys то есть, тип к которому приводится операнд определяется другим операндом, как я написал выше? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562588/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/563494#comment737129_563494

Answer (score 2):

А почему небо голубое? Хм, да, рэлеевское рассеяние. Не суть.

Потому что типы определяются во время исполнения (как именно - ясно из контекста), а так же неявно преобразуются.
К примеру, можно делать так и ошибки не будет:

```
$string = 'Test';
$number = 42;

print $string . $number . "\n"; # Test42\n
```

http://goo.gl/uLMxf3

Что говорит о том, что `Perl` автоматом разбирается с типами, что и подтверждает вики:

> Все версии Perl выполняют автоматическую типизацию данных и
>   автоматический контроль над памятью.
>
> ---
>
> Перевод одного типа данных в другой — например, числа в строку — происходит автоматически во время исполнения, невозможные для
>   выполнения переводы типов данных приводят к фатальной ошибке.

---

Сильная же типизация предполагает переменным быть всё существование одним типом (или явное приведение), в функциях использовать только те сигнатуры, которые описаны, перегрузка операторов, если поддерживается, тоже должна быть указана.
И т. п.

Comment: *Строковой* оператор `.` конвертирует операнды в строки, где тут *неявное* преобразование? Кажется, вы просто не поняли вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Perl является динамическим языком. Поэтому и не имеет типов вовсе (в понимании С/С++). В некотором смысле - это является его преимуществом.
Вместо типов у Perl есть контексты:

- Строковый
- Числовой
- Булевский
- Скалярный
- Списковый
- Void (Пустой)
- Интерполятивный (double-quote context)

> Для строк и чисел существуют разные операторы, таким образом, конвертация между ними не является неявной.

Нет, конвертация как раз происходит неявно. Просто в коде мы должены указывать, что ожидаем: строки или числа. Без дополнительного оператора нужно было бы городить костыли в некоторых случаях. А так всё просто и красиво:

```
'1a' == '1b' # TRUE    1 == 1
'1a' eq '1b' # FALSE   '1a', '1b' строки разные
 1   == '1b' # TRUE    1 == 1
 1   eq '1b' # FALSE   '1', '1b'  строки разные
```

Comment: *"Потому что Perl является динамическим языком. Поэтому и не имеет типов вовсе"* - вы путаете слабую и динамическую типизации. *"Нет, конвертация как раз происходит неявно. Просто в коде мы должены указывать, что ожидаем: строки или числа."* - это в моем понимании и есть *явная* конвертация, т.к. тип в который конвертировать *явно* задается программистом.